# does rails have a 'response.write', want to do quick output from an action

Tags: ruby-on-rails

From **within an action** (not the view), I want to output some quick debug code.

Does rails have a method for this?

in asp.net I would do:

```
Response.Write("hello");
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That'd be this:

```
render :text => "hello"
```

You can only call render or redirect once for a single request, just FYI.

Comment: @Blankman If it's no good, you should post your solution and accept it. For good form's sake.

Answer (score 6):

You may also use the logger. Put

```
logger.info "text"
logger.info @var
```

somewhere on the action. And then `tail -f log/development.log`

This way you won't interfere with the normal rendering process, since you can only use render once.