# Ruby on Rails - How to respond to Google Wallet's post request with the orderId

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, android-pay

I'm using Google Wallet and I need to send a response to Google's post request with the decoded `order_id`.  Here is the tutorial I'm following: https://developers.google.com/commerce/wallet/digital/training/getting-started/handle-notif .  Google checks `(response.status == 200) && (response.content == orderId)`, from [this documentation](https://developers.google.com/commerce/wallet/digital/docs/postback).  How do I add a custom `content` method to the response object, return the orderId as a header, or something else?  I've looked through the [API docs](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionDispatch/Response.html#method-i-body_parts) and did not see anything that would help.

The order does not go through because I'm not sending back the order id.  If I don't use a "postback url", the order goes through.  Also, I have removed log in walls from the controller.

Here is my controller's create action:

```
def create
  @postback_jwt = JWT.decode(params[:jwt], ENV['GOOGLE_WALLET_SECRET'])
  order_id = @postback_jwt["response"]["orderId"]
  render :new
end
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to EdSF for the guidance:

```
def create
  @postback_jwt = JWT.decode(params[:jwt], ENV['GOOGLE_WALLET_SECRET'])
  order_id = @postback_jwt["response"]["orderId"]
  render :new
  response.body = order_id
end
```

Another option:

```
def create
  @postback_jwt = JWT.decode(params[:jwt], ENV['GOOGLE_WALLET_SECRET'])
  order_id = @postback_jwt["response"]["orderId"]
  render text: order_id
end
```

The order of the response and render through me off.  The `response.body...` line needs to go below the `render...` line.  Otherwise the render will clear the body.  And `redirect` doesn't work.

Neither work in development because you can't have a postback to localhost.  So testing has to be done on a production/staging server.

Comment: Do you have a complete example for the complete google wallet procedure in rails? Would love an example app on github!

Comment: Not online.  I've been meaning to do a blog post or something.  Since it is hard to find a Rails-Google wallet example.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not a ruby person (am WISA) so unsure if this will help:

In ASP (classic or .Net) you would write the orderId in the *response body* e.g.

```
Response.ContentType = "text/plain";
Response.Write(orderId);
```

I think this [SO post: does rails have a 'response.write'](https://stackoverflow.com/q/4062897/304683) will be helpful.

Hth..

Comment: Thanks.  `render text: 'hello'` replaces the html with whatever you provide, 'hello' in this case.  I tried adding the orderId in the response body, but will try again.  Maybe I'm not doing it right.

Comment: `render text: order_id` does work, also.  If you add that, I will accept your answer.

Comment: @d_rail Wouldn't want to claim any Ruby expertise, so it's probably better if you add that to your answer and mark it as [the answer to your own question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/self-answer) :)